# Single bit gates and fixed position gates for Universality

Tags: logic, fixed, universal

Is it possible to make an arbitrary logic circuit using only single bit gates (Single input, single output) and some multiple bit gates (*n* bits in *m* bits out where *n* and *m* are any integers) which must be in a fixed position.

Or to ask the question another way:

Presume there exists a circuit which has some multiple bit gates in some fixed locations and many empty spaces where other gates may be inserted.

Would I be able to make an arbitrary program if I choose to only put in single input, single output logic gates in these empty places?

Would I require that the original circuit with fixed gates is infinitely large or exponentially bigger than the normal circuit for the same piece of logic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to myself incase others read this - Yes, this is universal.

Any 2-bit-input/1-bit-output gate may be constructed by using two 1-bit-input/1-bit-output gates in two predefined places.

From here universality follows.